# fusion of two arrays sorted

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

```
void fus(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m) {
    int j, k, d = n + m;
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; j < m && i < n && k < d; i++, j++, k++) {
        if ((*(A+i)) < (*(B+j))) {
            (*(C+k)) = (*(A+i));
        } else
            (*(C+k)) = (*(B+j));
    }
}
```

Do I have the possibility to put all these condition in `for`?

I don't know why it doesn't work, and I wanted to get a sorted array

Comment: `i` and `j` don't have to be incremented in every iteration. Increment `i` if `A[i] < B[j]` and `j` else.

Comment: still doesn't work , beacause if we will increment i as u said we will not have value of the second array .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbid76 found the issue.

It's easier/clearer to do (e.g.) `A[i]` than `*(A + i)`

Also, if the `A` and `B` are different lengths [which they can be in a merge sort merge operation], we need two additional loops to copy the remainder of the longer of `A` or `B`

Also, it's better to use more descriptive names than `i`, `j`, etc.

Here's a corrected version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
fus(int *A, int *B, int *C, int nA, int nB)
{
    int iC = 0;
    int iA = 0;
    int iB = 0;

    for (;  (iA < nA) && (iB < nB);  ++iC) {
        if (A[iA] <= B[iB])
            C[iC] = A[iA++];
        else
            C[iC] = B[iB++];
    }

    for (;  iA < nA;  ++iA, ++iC)
        C[iC] = A[iA];

    for (;  iB < nB;  ++iB, ++iC)
        C[iC] = B[iB];
}
```

Comment: Your remark on the need to copy the remaining elements of `A` or  `B` is correct, but a non-sequitur: it is unrelated to the lengths of `A` and `B`. It is always needed.

Comment: @chqrlie Interesting. But, IMO, due to the "strength" of _can_ and _need_, the sentence does _not_ imply the loops are optional, only that the length mismatch is optional. However, we could do: `s/if the/if and when the/` or `s/if the/to cover the case when the/`

Comment: @chqrlie But, also, the additional loops _are_ optional if the lengths match, and we could have a "fast path" function `fus_fast` that eliminates them, takes a single length arg `nC`, and the single loop condition: `iC < nC;` Then, `fus` becomes `fus_slow`, and we now have `void fus(int *A,int *B,int *C,int nA,int nB) { if (nA == nB) fus_fast(A,B,C,nA * 2); else fus_slow(A,B,C,nA,nB); }` Fast path _always_ occurs if array length is a power of 2, and [since he's learning] OP may have started with that assumption.

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken: the first loop stops when `(iA < nA) && (iB < nB)` fails and the only possibility for this condition to fail for both `iA` and `iB` is if `nA` and `nB` were both `0` to start with. Otherwise, since only one of `iA` and `iB` gets incremented in the loop body, both conditions cannot fail at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

i and j don't have to be incremented in every iteration. Increment i if A[i] < B[j] and j else.

Create a loop which continues as long `i<n` and `j<m`:

```
for(i=0, j=0, k=0; j<m && i<n; k++)
{
    if ( A[i] < B[j] )
       C[k] = A[i++];
    else
       C[k] = B[j++];
}
```

At the end of this loop either `i == n` or `j == m`, but it can't be fullfilled both.
So you have to copy the missing rest to the container:

```
for(; i<n; i++, k++)
    C[k] = A[i];
for(; j<m; j++, k++)
    C[k] = B[j];
```

The full code may look like this:

```
void fus(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m)
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;

    for(; j<m && i<n; k++)
        C[k] = A[i] < B[j] ? A[i++] : B[j++];

    for(; i<n; i++, k++)
        C[k] = A[i];
    for(; j<m; j++, k++)
        C[k] = B[j];
}
```

Of course this can be even expressed shorter:

```
void fus(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m)
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;  
    while (i<n || j<m)
        C[k++] = i!=n && (j==m || A[i] < B[j]) ? A[i++] : B[j++];
}
```

Comment: This is a very compact alternative, at the cost of many redundant tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should only increment `i` or `j` depending on which element you take. Futhermore, there is no need to test `k` against `d`, this test is redundant with the tests on `i` and `j`.

Note also that the fusion is not complete unless you finish copying the remaining elements from `A` or `B` when `i == n` or `j == m`.

Here is a corrected and improved version with fewer tests, using the array index syntax:

```
void fus(const int *A, const int *B, int *C, int n, int m) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    if (i < n && j < m) {
        for (;;) {
            if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
                C[k++] = A[i++];
                if (i == n)
                    break;
            } else {
                C[k++] = B[j++];
                if (j == m)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (i < n)
        C[k++] = A[i++];
    while (j < m)
        C[k++] = B[j++];
}
```

Comment: what the for(;;) stands for ?

Comment: @Aladin: it is a `for` loop without a condition, meaning forever loop, equivalent to `while (true) {...`